# Initializing global variable on Perl module (with BEGIN block) include

Tags: perl

I'm trying to initialize a global variable from a Perl module that has a `BEGIN` block, but I can't manage to get it work.

This is the Perl module

```
Package A::B;
our $var;

BEGIN{
  $var ||= "/some/default/path";

  #create/access files/folders in $var
}
```

This is my CGI script

```
use A::B;
$A::B::var = "/correct/path";
```

But `#error` returned because $var is not the correct path

The `BEGIN` block is being executed before the correct path is assigned to `$var`. Is there a way to work around this without having to remove code from the `BEGIN` block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
BEGIN { $A::B::var = "/correct/path" }
use A::B;
```

This answer is unsatisfying to me, but I can't think of any other way, given how your A::B is designed.  Ideally a module doesn't depend on who is using it or how often, but this module can really only be used once.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you.

I did this this way because $var determines the location of a database that can differ from system to system